# Convert HTML/CSS into plain HTML

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to convert HTML + CSS into HTML for a system that doesn't handle CSS, not even inline CSS?

What options do I have?

Comment: BIG STATIC IMAGES! Hooray :D EDIT: What systems don't handle CSS?

Comment: @Alastair: I don't actually know what the system is - only that I have been told it doesn't handle css

Comment: @Casebash: ask exactly what the system is. You can't give an informed opinion if you are not informed nor a correct implementation if you have extremely fuzzy requirements. A non-CSS capable browser can mean many things, from IE3 to a screen reader, passing through `links`.

Comment: @Alastair: Blackberry, for example.

Comment: @Seva: Huh, well there you go. I didn't know that.

Comment: On the Blackberry browser, even JavaScript is turned off by default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Much of what CSS does is not possible with HTML alone. Your best option is to design your site in such a way that when it loses CSS, it still renders in a nice and orderly fashion. Pay very close attention to things like Heading Tags, paragraph tags, lists, etc. Be sure to build semantically-correct sites, and they (in most cases) will degrade quite nicely.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you can do is add styles that were possible with old html3+ attributes and font tags. Quite a bit of stuff is possible, but none of it is going to be automatic. You can go through pretty much everything in css and try to find it's html3+ attribute equivalent.

Things like `background` `font` `b` `i` `center` `width` `height` are examples of old attributes (or tags in the case of `font`) that define style (and should generally be ignored these days). I don't envy the work ahead of you, but just make a happy medium between reasonable things and unreasonable styles. Tables also might come in handy for floats as well.

Sounds like an old mobile device?

Comment: I guess I didn't make it very clear, but definitely not everything is possible, but you can get the general picture...

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use any CSS, I would imagine you would have to resort to possibly deprecated HTML tags/attributes, like font tags and attributes like bgcolor.

This would probably be rather difficult, because to my knowledge you can't achieve everything you can do with CSS, like positioning for example. You would have to switch your layout to use tables and set `align`, `valign`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

use this first

http://www.mailchimp.com/labs/inlinecss.php

then replace css with deprecated html

http://www.highdots.com/css-editor/articles/css_equiv.html

Answer (score 0):

Two words: Image Maps :) (I've actually seen sites that, in order to "render correctly on every browser" literally just make a big fancy image the background, and add links accordingly via an image map)

Comment: If this is some kind of text browser (like `links`) that would be worse than nothing ;)

Comment: Oh yes, I hoped my recommendation was not taken seriously :)